# gas line location for natural gas clothes dryer

Tags: code-compliance, dryer, gas, natural-gas

In the US, what are the usual code requirements governing where you can put a gas clothes dryer relative to the gas line, and governing length and clearance for the flexible gas line between wall and dryer?

Specifically, is there usually a code requirement that the gas line for a clothes dryer is immediately in back of the dryer?  I noticed this "must be in back" requirement when Home Depot installs a dryer and was wondering if this is a code requirement or Home Depot's requirement.

I'm asking because our current dryer is recessed into a "nook" in the laundry room but the gas line comes out of the wall to the right of the nook. The flexible gas tubing is attached to the gas line, snakes back and left about 12 inches, goes through the 2-inch gap between dryer and right wall of the nook, and finally hooks up to the dryer. See below (apologies for ASCII art).

```
||============||
||            ||          
||  "nook" ***||
||         * *||
||  ---------*||
||  |       |*|=====||
||  |       |*      ||
||  | dryer |*****--|| <- gas line comes out here (* = flexible gas tubing)
||  |       |       ||     
||  |       |       ||
```

The nook is clearly a do-it-yourself add-on from house's previous owner (e.g. walls in back of the nook are plywood!).  There are built-in shelves over the area where the gas line is so no one is going to step on the gas line, but that doesn't mean it's up to code!  ;-)  Judging by (poorly) filled-in holes in the linoleum floor, the original dryer location was did indeed have the gas line directly in back of it, as Home Depot recommends, but I'd prefer to keep the current location because it yields more room in our small laundry area.

Comment: You also have to consider the appliance specifications - usually the appliance manual will list acceptable locations for the gas line.

Answer (score 2):

The [International Fuel Gas Code](https://law.resource.org/pub/us/code/ibr/icc.ifgc.2012.html) does not mention any line routing requirements.  (See section 613.)

If it were me, I would fasten some wood blocking to protect the gas line from being pinched by the dryer should it walk or be moved.  It should probably go along the right edge of the nook, especially at the front, and at the front of the right side of the original space.  2x4 flat against the wall should be more than enough.

Comment: I believe there is a requirement that the flexible appliance connector be no more than 6 feet in length.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things that you might want to consider

> ## International Fuel Gas Code 2012
>
> ### Chapter 4 - Gas Piping Installations
>
> #### Section 411 - Appliance and Manufactured Home Connections
>
> **411.1.2 Protection against damage.** Connectors and tubing shall be installed so as to be protected against physical damage.
>
> **411.1.3.1 Maximum length.** Connectors shall have an overall length not to exceed 6 feet (1829 mm). Measurement shall be made along the centerline of the connector. Only one connector shall be used for each appliance.
>
> **411.1.3.4 Shutoff valve.** A shutoff valve not less than the nominal size of the connector shall be installed ahead of the connector in accordance with Section 409.5.

As long as there is a shutoff valve ahead of the connector, the connector is protected from physical damage, and the connector is less than 6' in length. There shouldn't be a problem.

---

Additional code

> #### Section 404 - Piping System Installation
>
> **404.16 Location of outlets.** The unthreaded portion of piping outlets shall extend not less than l inch (25 mm) through finished ceilings and walls and where extending through floors or outdoor patios and slabs, shall not be less than 2 inches (51 mm) above them. The outlet fitting or piping shall be securely supported. Outlets shall not be placed behind doors. Outlets shall be located in the room or space where the appliance is installed.